# How do I handle a level 4 outbreak?

Tags: atom-zombie-smasher

In Atom Zombie Smasher, I tend to do well at the level 1 and 2 outbreaks - I can kill all the zeds in level 1 (as long as I get infantry) and most of the time in level 2.

I can reliably evacuate level 3, though I usually only get bronze medals.

But how are you supposed to beat level 4 outbreaks?  The best I can usually manage is to contain them by conquering the surrounding territories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used the following strategies for dealing with level 4 outbreaks. They are listed in order of general effectiveness:

1. **Use the Elephantbird Cannon.** This weapon can make short work of a level 4 Zed outbreak on its own. Unfortunately, it is only available to you once in a standard 6000-point game.
2. **Wait for a month with a long daytime.** If you don't have the Elephantbird Cannon, this is essential. Whatever you do, *never tackle a level 4 outbreak during a month with a short daytime.*
3. **Upgrade your artillery and the Catbird Cannon.** Increase your artillery's reload speed whenever you are given the opportunity *and* spend research points on leveling up the Catbird Cannon. The faster you can fire artillery *and* the Catbird, the better.
4. **Combine artillery, infantry, snipers, and Zed Bait.** This obviously entails a bit of luck in a standard game, but if you don't have the Elephantbird you really need (upgraded) artillery, infantry, and snipers to have a chance at clearing a level 4 outbreak. Zed Bait can also be helpful to bunch Zed together so that you can hit them with the Catbird and artillery.

Answer (score 3):

First off, remember that you don't have to take your helicopter on a level 4 raid as there's no one to rescue, so use that slot for an additional squad.

Second, the goal is to kill all the zombies before night time, and you get a bit more time to do so.  You'll want to take speedy killing squads rather than slow ones (like the snipers).  The best way I've found is to take a squad of barrier placers, a squad of sappers, and as many high leveled troops as possible (an upgraded artillery squad is especially useful and can replace the sappers).

Try to funnel the zombies with your barriers so multiple spawn points are forced to traverse down one path.  Place your infantry there (if you have any), and place the explosive charges at the places where you think they will merge together and detonate them when the time is proper.

Comment: I'm not able to select my squads - how do you do this?

Comment: I didn't realize that this was possible either, @Jeff

Comment: Once you complete a whole game (for better or for worse), when you start a new game there are many more options including being able to pick your own troops

Comment: yup, I forgot that was an option and not default :P  I guess you'll have to hope to get lucky with the artillery